# GIMP: if change size of something in layer beyond the canvas size, how do you change canvas size to match the new larger size?

Tags: gimp, resize

I take a graphic into gimp (so one layer), and canvas and layer size match.  Then I do a transformation on the graphic (in this case filters->distorts->curve-bend), that results in it going beyond the layer/canvas size.

I've tried the layer to boundary size command to increase the size of the layer  as desired to fit the new larger graphic size, but it seems to have no effect (? because the layer size can't go beyond the canvas size?).

Since I have a bunch of graphics to process, I'd like to find/use a command to automatically set the canvas size to the new graphic transformed size.  Is this possible to do?

If not, does GIMP do macros, and is there a macro command that can be easily built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layers can be bigger than the Canvas(*). To enlarge the canvas to fit existing  layers use (tadaaaa....) `Image>Fit canvas to layers`.

(*) Not that the selection is always clipped to the canvas, so if you have `Select>All`, changes on a larger layer will only apply inside the canvas "porthole", while with `Select>None` changes will apply to the whole layer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that does the trick (part 1).  I re-read your second comment//explanation several times, but I couldn't "get it."  Can you please reword/clarify?  Please note apparently I don't have enough user credit to issue an up vote.

Comment: In other words, you cannot have selected pixels outside of what you see on the canvas. So when you have bigger layer this can can have surprising results.